# SQL query sorted by id's with predefined names

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, select

I have the following SQL table

```
ID  |   country_id  |   name
1       33           test1
2       77           test3
3       33           test5
4       1            test6
5       77           test7
6       33           test8
```

I want to order this by country_id where each country_id has it's own name (but not in another database).

EX:

```
$countries = array(
    77 => 'Macedonia',
    33 => 'Uruguay',
    1  => 'Ghana'
);
```

So the result would be something like this:

```
 ID    |   country_id         |  name
 4         1  (G hana)        test6
 2         77 (M acedonia)    test3
 5         77 (M acedonia)    test7
 1         33 (U ruguay)      test1
 3         33 (U ruguay)      test5
 6         33 (U ruguay)      test8
```

Comment: Do you not have a table which maps the country_id to the country names by which you would like to order? If not, why not?  If country names only reside in application code, then I would just leave ordering up to application. Otherwise, you are going to have a tightly coupled, fragile solution, with trying to order in DB based on some country mapping that exists elsewhere.

Comment: no, i don't have another table. and i can't create one.

Comment: Why even have a country id in the database if you can;t have another table that maps those id's to something useful?  Perhaps just replace id's with country names if you can modify schema of this table.  Also seems odd to me that you wouldn't be able to create a table. If someone wants you to do this work and implement this functionality, they need to let you potentially change the schema.

Comment: I have only three country types which can change at any time so I don't see the reason why I should build a table for only three tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be interested in MySQL's [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function which will allow you to define a custom `ORDER BY` query:

```
SELECT
    id, country_id, name
FROM
    countries
ORDER BY
    FIELD(country_id, 77, 33, 1);
```

`FIELD()` allows you to define an "ordered list" and then checks what index/position in the list the value you pass in is located at; you can use that to generate your custom `ORDER BY`.

If you have an array in PHP like you showed with `$countries`, you could easily generate the query with:

```
$country_ids = join(',', array_keys($countries));
$fieldClause = 'FIELD(country_id, ' . $country_ids . ');'
```

Alternatively, if you have a second reference table that contains country names, you could `JOIN` against that:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.country_id, a.name
FROM
    your_table a
    JOIN countries c
        on a.country_id = c.id
ORDER BY
    c.name;
```

I would recommend the latter approach since it's more portable.

Comment: Ok but than how does it know that 77 is asigned to Macedonia, 33 to Uruguay and so on. Also the sorting has to be done automatically based on the asigned names to the ID's.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu You said you have a predefined list; if you don't have a relationship table, you're going to have to do some hardcoding (i.e. you write in the order that they're supposed to be in). I've updated my answer to show a quick example how you can do it with PHP using your example `$countries` array if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `$countries` array, sort it and use it in the `ORDER BY`:

```
sort($countries);
$order = implode(', ', array_keys($countries));
```

Now the array is sorted by the values and you can use the keys as the order in `FIELD()` as shown by **newfurniturey**:

```
SELECT id, country_id, name
FROM countries
ORDER BY FIELD(country_id, $order);
```

However, even with only 3 countries I would create another table and join that.